# Cashing out deposit on Pokerstars

Tags: online, tournament

I am looking to set up a home game tournament with some friends, but I would like it to be a real-money tournament rather than play money. However, I would like a small buy-in amount (~£1), but the minimum deposit in Pokerstars is £7.

Question:
Would it be possible for my friends and I to deposit the minimum amount in the Pokerstars client software (£7), enter the tournament, and then cash-out everything that is left? I.e. Deposit £7, enter tournament for £1.00 + £0.10, then cash-out the remaining £5.90?

I have read [Pokerstars' FAQ](http://www.pokerstars.com/poker/real-money/cashier/faq/#group6), but I couldn't find the answer to my question.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not. I know the minimum deposit for me is $10 USD and the minimum withdrawal is $10 USD so I'm assuming the same deposit/withdrawal restrictions would apply for you. Your best bet is probably to just deposit the minimum plus whatever you want to use for buy-ins. In this case, £7 + £1.00 + £0.10. Then after you play your tournament you can withdraw the remainder.

You can also go the route of just having one of you deposit the money needed for all of your buy-ins. You can then transfer one buy-in to each of your friends. That might be easier.

Comment: Thank you! I should have found out the minimum withdrawal amount before asking the question.
Do you know if I can instantly deposit and then withdraw the remaining amount? (I did a quick search and couldn't find anything)

Comment: Edit, found answer: http://www.bankrollmob.com/userimages/2013/4548.jpg